# Laravel - update data into 2 related tables failed

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 application, I have these two (2) related models:

In my Laravel-5.8, I have these three (3) models:

**Identity**

```
class Identity extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'identity';

    protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'name',
          ];
    public function parameter()
    {
       return $this->hasOne(Parameter::class, 'identity_id');
    }    
}
```

**Parameter**

```
class Parameter extends Model
{    
    protected $table = 'parameters';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
                  'activate_goal',
                  'active_year',
                  'identity_id',
              ];

    public function identity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Identity','identity_id');
    }
}
```

Request Rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'appraisal_name' => [
            'required', 
            'min:5',
            'max:100',           
        ],       
        'activate_goal' => [
            'required',
        ], 
        'activate_year' => [
            'nullable',
        ], 
    ];
}
```

Then follows the controller:

IdentityController

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $identity = Identity::where('id', $id)->first();   
    $parameter = Parameter::where('identity_id', $id)->first();
    return view('identities.edit')
            ->with('identity', $identity)
            ->with('parameter', $parameter);
}

public function update(UpdateIdentityRequest $request, $id)
{        
    $identity = Identity::find($id);  
    $identity->name           = $request->name;
    $identity->save();

    $parameter = Parameter::where('identity_id', $id)->fiirst();     
    $parameter->activate_goal           = $request->has('activate_goal');
    $parameter->activate_year           = $request->has('activate_year');          
    $parameter->save();            
}
```

Then Finally the view blade for edit identity:

```html
<form action="{{route('identities.update', ['id'=>$identity->id])}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label text-right col-md-0"> Name<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="appraisal_name" placeholder="Enter appraisal name here" class="form-control" value="{{old('name',$identity->name)}}">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="form-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Activate Goal?:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="activate_goal" class="form-control" unchecked data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="NO" data-on-text="YES" @if($parameter->activate_goal == 1) checked @endif value="{{old('activate_goal')}}">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label"> Activate Year?:</label><br>
              <input type="checkbox" name="activate_year" class="form-control" unchecked data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success" data-off-text="NO" data-on-text="YES" @if($parameter->activate_year == 1) checked @endif value="{{old('activate_year')}}">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Identity is the main table and it has its identity_id in Parameter. When Identity: name, Parameter: activate_goal and activate_year fields are entered, the application takes the id from Identity and update it as identity_id in Parameter table.

This was successful in Insert (create). But, however on update I got this error:

```
The activate goal is required
```

But this is selected as checkbox.

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an error in code

**change this**

```
$parameter = Parameter::where('identity_id', $id)->fiirst();
```

**to**

```
$parameter = Parameter::where('identity_id', $id)->first();
```

Comment: What's the difference between the two codes?  Thanks

Comment: `fiisrt()` spell mistake